# d3 custom space between nodes in cluster layout

Tags: d3.js, cluster-computing

I'm creating custom cluster, where each node with status "D" has different size of circle denoting it. Some nodes don't have any circle.

My problem is, that some circles overlap, meanwhile the simple nodes next to it have too big space between them. 
I would like to set the space between nodes and their branches according to the size of circle.

```
var root = {    
 "name": "cs4001",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "cs3212",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cs2121",
     "status": "D"
    }]
  },
     {
         "name": "cp2121",
         "status": "D"
     },
     {
         "name": "cp21214"
     },
     {
         "name": "cp21215"
     }

 ]
};

(function(root) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
  links = cluster.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
   .data(links)
   .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
   .data(nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
     .attr("class", "node")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x +      ")"; })

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {return d.status=="D" ? 70: null} );

  node.append("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.children ? -8 : 8; })
    .attr("dy", 3)
    .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children ? "end" : "start"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
})(root);
```

I updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6Gx/1/) I found first in the google to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You should make two changes in the cluster layout. First, instead of `.size` you must use `.nodeSize` and define `.separation` function to find desired distances between two nodes.

The distance between two nodes is calculated by multiplying the vertical parameter given in `.nodeSize` and the return value of the given separation function for the two nodes.

I updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ6Gx/2/) to show these changes in action.